# 7-zip for MacOS man page missing

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source

Starting from [this page](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sevenzip), I tried to install a program for manipulating 7-zip-files using

```
brew install sevenzip
```

Interestingly, this installed an executable named `7zz`, but no man-page for it. While running `7zz` without parameters produces a short overview of the command line flags, a more detailed description would be appreciated.

The aforementioned Homebrewpage refers to the site https://7-zip.org/ for further information, but according to this page, 7-zip is only available for Windows (although  the `7zz` I got is clearly a Mac executable), and I don't find a documentation for the command line switches there either.

Does anybody now where to get the information I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man pages are not a requirement of any utility and if the dev or someone else didn't create them, they won't be available.

7-zip.org and Homebrew are two totally distinct entities and not related with each other.  Because there's a Formulae or Cask isn't a developer endorsement of a particular platform.  It just means a maintainer (a person) chose to create the Formulae/Cask and make it available.  Don't make the assumption that because it exists there, the developer supports it. An excellent example of this is Microsoft's [Visual Studio code available via FreshPorts](https://www.freshports.org/editors/vscode/) for FreeBSD (Microsoft doesn't support this at all).

That said, there are Linux and even macOS source versions available on the [Source Forge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/23.01/7z2301-src.tar.xz/download).  They can be downloaded and compiled on your own machine.  After a looking through the source, there's no man pages that I could find.

Bottom line:  the man pages don't exist; at least from the original/official  developer.

Answer (score 3):

I have 7zip installed by MacPorts and the manpage is installed.

```
[crystalwell:fd0] $ whatis 7z
7z(1)                    - A file archiver with highest compression ratio
```

There is even html documentation.

```
HTML Documentation
       /opt/local/share/doc/p7zip/DOC/MANUAL/index.htm
```

Comment: `p7zip` as stated by the developer, is [made and maintained by an independent dev](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html).  But +1 for finding some sort of man page associated with this tool.

Comment: Thank you. I can see now, that `sevenzip` and `p7zip` are different implementations for processing 7z-file.

Comment: (FWIW, `p7zip` can also be installed from Homebrew — and includes the manpage there too.)

Answer (score 2):

From the link (https://7-zip.org/) given in your question, there is this link (https://7-zip.org/download.html) to the Download page. If you select 7-Zip 23.01 (2023-06-20) for macOS (arm64 / x86-64) console version, then the file `7z2301-mac.tar.xz` will download. If you open this file with the Archive Utility (which is the default application), a folder named `7z2301-mac` will be created. In this folder, you will find a folder named `Manual` which contains the file `start.htm`. If you open `start.htm` in a web browser (such as Safari), then you will access an offline version of the 7-Zip manual. This manual includes a "User's Guide for the command line version".

> Note: This download also contains the executable `7zz`, so you may not have to use `brew` to get 7-Zip. You will probably need to remove the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute.